# Precision in timestamp value is periodically omitted in response

Tags: karate

I'm calling an API that returns a date from a Postgres DB. The column is defined with a timestamp data type. It appears that precision is getting omitted periodically in the response.

This is the format that is expected - "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmmZ" and confirmed to be in the Postgres DB.

However, what is periodically returned is -  "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ"

Making the exact same GET call using curl or Postman (plus an internal tool) they all return the expected value and format.

Our first thought was if the precision was all zero's (e.g ".000") it was getting dropped, but none of the values where the precision is omitted are all zeros.

We've worked around this via regex, but was wondering if there is some possible configuration setting or header that I should be setting?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound good, and it would be really great if you can replicate, but I know it may be hard: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - maybe you can experiment returning the same payload via a Karate mock and trying to call that API in a loop.

The only thing that I can guess may be a factor is encoding. If Karate is not running with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` it can cause some problems when the server returns special characters. Please try the settings mentioned here in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fileencoding

Comment: Yes, providing a reproducible test will not be easy... I did confirmed that `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is being passed to the `Gradle Test Executor`